# Help! Too much pressure in cooling system

Tags: cooling-system, buick, regal

So I have a 1980 Buick regal with a Pontiac 265 v8 mated to a th200.. I am having issues with the cooling system. I have  replaced a dozen thermostats and 3 radiators. and 3 aftermarket coolant temp gauges.... when I  fly up to 60 mph coolant will go through the cap and only push coolant out into overflow and out of that.. To me it seems as if there is too much pressure not allowing it to circulate.  I start the day with the radiator overflow full and I end the day with an 4/5 empty radiator and no overflow.

Comment: Do you have the correct psi  radiator cap?

Comment: Sounds like it's time for an upgrade to a 383 stroker to me :o) Haha, jk. Agree with cano ... make sure you have the right radiator cap. If that doesn't work, check to see if you have hydrocarbons in your radiator (head gasket leak into cooling system).

Comment: Yes, as suggested check the rad cap pressure rating. Also, does it seal correctly? Is the seal damaged or the surface it mates to damaged? Have you replaced the cap? Or all the other components except the cap?

Comment: What is the highest temp reading you see on the gauge?